# Should I use var in the for in construct?

Tags: javascript, var, for-in-loop

I make use of a for in loop in a piece of JavaScript logic.
Should I use the var keyword or not?

When I run a for-in loop as per W3School's example, without the var then, as a side effect, it gets defined as a property on the global scope (window):

```
(function () {

  var object = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
  }
  for (varName in object) {
      alert(varName + " is" + object[varName])
  }

})();

alert(window.varName) //Returns "b" !
//This returns undefined when the for-in is rewritten as for (var varName in object).
```

edit: here is a fiddle of the above code for your enjoyment: http://jsfiddle.net/94uEh/

Which is the correct, preferred form? - Note that I wish to support IE 8 (EcmaScript < 5)

Comment: Don't use W3Schools - lots of typos and bad information. This is a better resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: RobH Yes, I completely agree. However, the Mozilla documentation contains a very similar example; " `for (variable in object) {
  ...
} `"

Comment: Well yes - neither `variable` nor `object` are defined - it's pseudocode to show the syntax; the examples are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `var`, if you want the value to be local.

Using the keyword `object` for a variable, is not recommended, you might run into undefined behavior across browsers.

Also you should generally avoid applying anything that is suppose to be local to the global scope.

**This is bad:**

```
for (varName in object) {
    alert(varName + " is" + object[varName])
}
```

**This is correct:**

```
for (var varName in object) {
    alert(varName + " is" + object[varName])
}
```

If you need to access this value in the global scope, you are probably doing it wrong. Also having this in the global scope is useless, as it will only be the last value, that will exist in the varName.

Comment: I have just tested this in IE8 (The browser that that I am to support), and using the `var` keyword there works as expected.

I am marking this as the answer.

P.S. I the choice of the name object was entirely for demonstration purposes and is not in actual use in my real code :)
But I am curious as to why both Mozilla and W3Schools documentation feature examples with bad coding guidelines. (they both omit var!).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. The Mozilla page features correct examples. W3Schools however just features bad code.

Comment: @Joeppie Yes W3Schools should be avoided if there are alternative sources. They are usually showing really lousy examples.

Comment: I notified W3Schools of their unfortunate example via the 'REPORT ERROR' link.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `var`, otherwise you are accessing a global variable (and there's a risk you are overwriting someone's else variable)